# Generic Platform Event - Centralize routing or not?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, platform-event, design-patterns

My App has a **single multipurpose Platform Event** called `MyEvent__e` which is emitted by **MANY publishers** and for **MANY Topics**.

Receivers and subscribers need to subscribe to the event type and then do filtering on the **Publisher** (a String) and a **Topic** (and URL-like String) to find out if they actually want to handle a specific event.

My naive train of thought was to just let different purpose-specific flows or Apex Event Triggers (Handlers) do that but then someone said: *"No you need a centralized Router. Otherwise it's super inefficient"*.

I tried it out and actually build one. But it just add complexity and syntactic sugar, but for a given complex matching I never gets better than ExD (for each event asked each subscriber if its relevant for it).

**So my questions are:**

1. Do I need central routing for Generic Platform Events?
2. Why or why not?
3. If you recommend it how does that handle 1001 Flows that bypass my central router?
4. Are there published best-practices or even Open-Source Apex routers?

Comment: It's hard to tell based on the information given how much overlap there might be between subscribers. Maybe some high level examples of what they do would help tie it together. To me, that's a core aspect of the solution space.

Comment: I'm sure there will be a super answer soon, even for the given limited information. But I'm happy to answer specific questions.

Comment: ^ That was my question. How much overlap is there between subscriber logic?

Comment: Complicated answer: I don't know in advance and I don't want to care about, because aligning the efforts of alls subscribers will not be possible.

Comment: Your question reminded some (unfinished) reasoning from months ago, at the time it was around using multiple events or not, order of execution, error handling, batching, etc... One question for you (maybe useful for your considerations, maybe you'll teach me smt :) -- in a "one event-multiple subscribers" architecture that doesn't keep control over subscribers (over event processing batch size and/or error handling)... what happens if a handler halts on event ID = 4? Does the processing of events go forward with event ID = 5 [without a secure wrapper in the middle that keeps the boat afloat]?

Comment: @MLucci not sure if I get your ordering problem. All processes wait for single events with distinct topics like ids.

Comment: Scenario: one event, multiple unmanaged/uncontrolled apex triggers (one from your app, others from subscribers). We don't care the order in which subscribers process a single event. My question is, if a single subscriber fails (excepts), does processing of events move forward with new events for all other subscribers? For a single subscriver an uncaught expection causes "the train" to stop for the apex handler (i.e. next batch of new events are not processed until recovery/success) afair. What's the behavior when there are multiple apex subscribers working on the same event stream?

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing something (smt in the documentation, or smt obvious) and my question has a simple answer, I think it connects with your original topic and question around if/why/which event handler architecture to choose. Thank you for coming back with a reply 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's almost certainly no need to unify your subscribers. For some use cases it may offer benefits, others not so much, but either way the lack of a unified subscriber or handling pattern is extremely unlikely to be detrimental to the point of crashing the system, and may actually perform better in the long run.

Especially when publishing some sort of ubiquitous event from a **managed package** where you really don't care how the event is handled, pushing for one consolidated way to handle the events seems to offer few benefits and more headaches. It's one of the advantages of the pub/sub model that you don't have to have any knowledge of or interest in how the subscribers work to use it effectively. I would push back and ask for more compelling arguments from your colleague before considering it.

Answer (score 1):

Likely not as Salesforce have a [filtering pilot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_platform_events_filtering_pilot.htm&type=5&release=232) in Summer '21. I would note the restriction though that this is for CometD subscribers only in the pilot. Hopefully Apex will be included when it goes GA.